# Find the first numeric word in a sentence

Tags: python

Lets say I have a paragraph such as

```
I have two years left for my school to end. 
I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town.

I have three years left for my school to end. 
I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town.
```

And I want to do the following:

1) Deconstruct the paragraph into a sentence
2) Figure out which sentence has the word 'school' in it and extract that sentence
3) For all of those sentences extracted, figure out which ones has a number in it (e.g. one, two, three etc.)
4) Figure out what is the first number and extract that number

For now I have the following code but I am sure there is a better more elegant way of going about this

```
txt = 'I have two years left for my school to end. 
I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town. I have three years left for my school to end. 
I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town.'
words = 'school'.split(' ')
sentences = re.findall(r"([^.]*\.)" ,txt)  
for sentence in sentences:
    if any(word in sentence for word in words):
        print(sentence.split('\n'))
```

The output from the code above

```
['I have two years left for my school to end.']
[' My school sucks but it is the second best school in town.']
[' I have three years left for my school to end.']
[' My school sucks but it is the second best school in town.']
```

Desired output would be

```
two
three
```

Comment: I wrote the above post with the MCVE code in mind. I am not sure where the issue is. Can you please help me out here?
I wrote a reproducible example. My problem. My attempt. And the desired output

Comment: One thing that is confusing me: what are you trying to accomplish with `'school'.split(' ')`, as this just returns `['school']`?

Comment: Your posted example doesn't follow your second step, and there's no list of number words.  Also, I'm confused as to how you expect "three" in the output when that word doesn't appear in the input.

Comment: `words = 'school'.split(' ')` should probably be `words = txt.split(' ')`

Comment: @G.Anderson I agree that part of the code is redundant. But as per the 4 steps I want to do, I am able to complete until step 2 i.e. split the paragraph into sentences and find sentences with school in it. I just cannot figure out how to do 3 or 4

Comment: @ 'three' does appear in the input and in the sentence 'I have three years left for my school to end'

Comment: For starters, you need a list of all the words you want to find; `num_list = ['one','two','three'...`, then you can split each sentence on whitespace, `sentence.split()`, then look for each word in the split sentence and return the first instance `[i for i in sentence if i in num_list][0]`. this doesn't get you all the way there, but might help get you close

Answer (score 0):

While your attempt was not accurate, I think you at least made an attempt, so here is what one solution could be: 
 - create a list of words you are looking to filter for, numbers[] below, and check against it

```
txt = "I have two years left for my school to end.I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town. I have three years left for my school to end./I have four apples at home. My school sucks but it is the second best school in town."
numbers = ["one","two","three", "four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
sentences = txt.split('.')
words = []

for i in sentences:
    words = i.split()

    # below checks whether the words in the sentence are in the list, numbers[]
    num = [k for k in words if k in numbers]

    if "school" in words and any(num):
        print(num[0])
```

Output:

```
two
three
```